# How to allow a user to send an sms message from a windows app sdk winui 3 application?

Tags: sms, microsoft-teams, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

In an application I developed for the mac I was able to easily launch a "Messages" window from my application that allowed the user to send themselves or someone else an sms message. I pre-filled the message body so they just had to pick a recipient and hit send. I'm trying to accomplish that in Windows 11 in a Windows App SDK desktop application. I was hoping there would be some kind of integration with Microsoft Teams to accomplish this but I can't figure it out. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Teams may not have built-in support for sending SMS messages.

If you require the functionality to send SMS messages from your Windows App SDK desktop application, you may need to consider alternative options. You can explore third-party SMS gateway services that provide APIs for sending SMS messages programmatically.